# insert datetime in postgres not same with my local time using codeigniter

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

I want to insert current date time in postgres database using date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), in Codeigniter's, its work but only on date , the time is not same as my local time in my computer its always -3 hours. already using LOCALTIME() and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP but its same. anyone know what should i do ?

**Controller**

```
$data = array(
                'id_user' => $id_user,
                'id_unit' => $id_unit['id_unit'],
                'id_status' => '1',
                'tgl_input' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'perihal' => $perihal,
                'isi' => $isi
                );

            $this->m_home->input_data($data,'t_aspirasi');
```

[screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oM92e.png)

**MODEL**

```
function input_data($data,$table){
       $this->db->insert($table,$data);
    }
```

Thanks for the answer..

Comment: You need to change default timezone in your php.ini.

Comment: thanks its work ! @ViswalingaSuryaS and how to change it auto detect my location?

Comment: That's quiet difficult. You have to get the client location by IP Address or by some means and can set the timzone in your PHP file itself.